# detecting duplicates and removing them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I've been trying to solve a problem in my database which is quite common but I couldn't find a solution so far and I hope you could help me with this.

I have a database with people and their associated addresses. My primary goal is to find out how many unique households are in there. For example, I want to count a family as one. So far a ran a query to display last_names and addresses which are more than one:

```
select  Last_Name ,add_line1, count(*)  from ##all_people 
  group by  Last_Name,ADD_LINE1
  having count(*) > 1
```

This shows me people with the same last_name and address but I need their IDs in order to remove them from my temptable.

Furthermore, I'd like to ask how it is possible to display only one record for each household.

This is the structure of my temptable:

```
ID      First_name   Last_Name    add_line1
```

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to find duplicates, you can use Count() Over() and partition by the grouping you want.

```
select * from (
select Id, Last_Name ,add_line1, count(*) over (partition by Last_Name, add_line1) dupe_count  from ##all_people 
) t
where t.dupe_count > 1
```

to find the ones you want to delete, you can use Row_Number()

```
select * from (
select Id, Last_Name ,add_line1, row_number() over (partition by Last_Name, add_line1 order by ID) extras  from ##all_people 
) t
where t.extras > 1
```

use `t.extras = 1` to see one row per grouping

Comment: Jamie! Thank you so much! You hit the nail on the head! So t.extra = 1 will only show me one record for each household right?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a lot of questions here...

> My primary goal is to find out how many unique households are in there.

You can do this with a distinct count:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Last_Name + add_line1)
FROM ##all_people
```

> ...but I need their IDs in order to remove them from my temptable

I think this is solved by the new count query.

> Furthermore, I'd like to ask how it is possible to display only one record for each household.

Just use distinct last name and address:

```
SELECT DISTINCT last_name, add_line1
FROM ##all_people
```